# PHP Mixed in with HTML not working

Tags: php, html, configuration

I set up a simple website, and on my local dev it worked just fine. However, once I pushed it to my VPS, it started acting a little funky. I am using PHP within the HTML, so I am doing something like this:

```
<?php
  include 'includes/header.php';

  $name = 'World';
?>

    Hello, <?php echo $name; ?>!

<?php
  include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

In this example, the header and footer show up fine (both files just have plain HTML inside), but the variable `$name`, does not. As opposed to seeing:

`Hello, World!`

I see:

`Hello, !`

I am not sure why this is happening. Since I have PHP 5.4 on both my local dev and VPS, I assume this is some sort of configuration issue.

Can anyone confirm, and if so, what setting(s) need to be changed?

Comment: did you saved with .php extension or .html

Comment: I used a .php extension.

Comment: looks strange. I have tested on localhost and on my server works perfect. Please make sure apache is configured properly. use   phpinfo() method to check the configuration. if possible restart apache and try again

Comment: create a sample php file <?php echo "Alec";?> if this doesn't execute then there is something wrong with apache

Answer (score 0):

if you try to add at this at the begenin of your script, do you see error?

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Also try to diplay the phpinfo

```
phpinfo();
```

And what is the result if you try this below:

```
<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL | E_STRICT);
  include 'includes/header.php';
  $name = 'Hello, World !';
  echo $name;
  echo ' trace';
  include 'includes/footer.php';
```